# ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In fear of being that guy that asks the question that has been asked already.....*I have looked through the various solutions to this problem, and  none seem to solve my problem.
I simply have a button that I would like to start a map activity.

Below is the activity:

```
  public void OnclickButtonListener() {
    button_map = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button_map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mapintent = new Intent("mf.tutorial.MapsActivity");
            startActivity(mapintent);
        }
    });
```

and the intent being handled in my manifest file:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The error returned looks like this:

```
ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=mf.tutorial.MapsActivity }
```

Any help is really appreciated as it has taken me ages to get this far and this is just the latest stumbling block. I would be happy to provide any other parts of the code that might be relevant for a solution!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming MapsActivity is an activity in your apk?  In that case, you would use `Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);`  The version of Intent you used is for running an activity that has an intent filter for a specific action.  Usually used to access system apps like the camera app or the dialer.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to launch your `Activity`, you do this:

```
    Intent mapintent = new Intent("mf.tutorial.MapsActivity");
```

This creates an `Intent` and sets the ACTION in that `Intent` to `"mf.tutorial.MapsActivity"`.

When you call `startActivity()`, Android tries to find an `Activity` in an installed application that knows how to deal with the ACTION `"mf.tutorial.MapsActivity"`. There aren't any, so you get the `ActivityNotFoundException`.

What you are want to do is to launch the `Activity` by explicit COMPONENT, and NOT by implicit ACTION. Do that like this:

```
    Intent mapintent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
    startActivity(mapintent);
```

Using the 2-argument constructor allows you to set the COMPONENT (in this case, `MapsActivity`) explicitly. The parameter `context` should be a reference to the calling `Activity`.